# MongoDB Aggregate group on a subfield using Java Driver

Tags: mongodb, scala, aggregation-framework

I would like to know if its possible to do a GroupCommand on a subfield using the MongoDB Java driver. I don't know how it can be expressed in the third param.

```
MongoDB.use(DefaultMongoIdentifier) { db =>
      var collection = db.getCollection(collectionName)
      var cmd = new GroupCommand(collection,
        null,
        new BasicDBObject("items", new BasicDBObject("field", 1)),
        new BasicDBObject("count", 0),
        "function ( curr, result ) {result.count++}",
        null);
      implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
      println(JObjectParser.serialize(collection.group(cmd)).extract[List[Map[String, String]]])
      JObjectParser.serialize(collection.group(cmd)).extract[List[Map[String, String]]]
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using the old group command instead of the aggregation framework?

Comment: No, I didn't know there was one ;)

Comment: Indeed since version 2.1 you can use: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/ You will probably want to add a $unwind to the group to do it on the subfield